# Are there general methods to optimize fixedupdate or multiscene physics for an android build?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have a game I am building for android. On Unity everything works and the apk file builds, but when I try to run the application on my Google pixel 6 it crashes after only being on for a couple seconds. I took a look at my unity profiler and I can tell a lot of this load is coming from my fixedupate function (see the large CPU spikes in image). Is there any general way to optimize fixed update or maybe slow down fixedupdate to be optimized for Android?

I am using fixedupdate to implement multiscene physics where each object has its own dedicated local physics scene within the scene.

```
        private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!sceneMainPhysics.IsValid())
            return;

        sceneMainPhysics.Simulate(Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
         void update()
    {
           //release velocity will always be a float
            void simProjectiles(releaseVelocity)

    }

    {
        if (!sceneMainPhysics.IsValid() || !scenePredictionPhysics.IsValid())
            return;

        Debug.Log("Time model is on");

        int j = 0;
        Debug.Log("Debugging positions for now");
        ball = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);

        ball.name = "whiteSphere";
        SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(ball, sceneMain);
        ball.transform.localScale = new Vector3(.1f, .1f, .1f);
        ball.AddComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = releaseVelocity;
        Material whiteMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Universal Render Pipeline/Lit"));
        whiteMaterial.color = Color.white;
        ball.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = whiteMaterial;
        ball.tag = "simCube";
        ball.GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = ball.GetComponent<Collider>().enabled;
        ball.transform.position = this.transform.position;
        ball.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;


        SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(sim_target, scenePrediction);
        foreach (Vector3 pos in this.positions)
        {
            GameObject predictionBall = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
            SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(predictionBall, scenePrediction);
            predictionBall.AddComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = releaseVelocity;
            predictionBall.tag = "simObj";
            predictionBall.name = "emptySphere";
            predictionBall.transform.localScale = new Vector3(.01f, .01f, .01f);
            predictionBall.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().collisionDetectionMode = CollisionDetectionMode.ContinuousDynamic;
            predictionBall.GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = predictionBall.GetComponent<Collider>().enabled;
            predictionBall.GetComponent<Collider>().isTrigger = true;
            predictionBall.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
            predictionBall.transform.position = pos;

            Material redMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Universal Render Pipeline/Lit"));
            redMaterial.color = Color.red;

            //If object was destroyed by target collider
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                scenePredictionPhysics.Simulate(Time.fixedDeltaTime);

                GameObject pathMarkSphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
                pathMarkSphere.GetComponent<Collider>().isTrigger = true;
                pathMarkSphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(.01f, .01f, .01f);
                pathMarkSphere.transform.position = predictionBall.transform.position;
                pathMarkSphere.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = redMaterial;
                pathMarkSphere.tag = "simObj";
                pathMarkSphere.GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = !pathMarkSphere.GetComponent<Collider>().enabled;
                pathMarkSphere.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;

                SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(pathMarkSphere, scenePrediction);
                singlePaths.Add(pathMarkSphere);

            }
            if (GlobalStates.simCollision == true)
            {
                yDistList.Add(Math.Abs(Target.dis_to_target));
            }
            GlobalStates.simCollision = false;
            allPaths.Add(singlePaths);
            singlePaths.Clear();


            j++;

        }
        int optimalIndex = 0;
        if (yDistList.Count() > 0)
        {
            float minVal = yDistList.Min();
            optimalIndex = yDistList.IndexOf(minVal);
        }
        else
        {

            Debug.Log("yDistList is empty");
        }


        this.transform.position = positions[optimalIndex];

        //Debug.Break();

    }
```

[image: Unity profiler when playing game in Unity editor on desktop]

Comment: Are you sure the crash is due to physics?  Check the device logs and post the relevant log(s) with your question.

Comment: @hijinxbassist I just uploaded an image of the unity profiler. Those large green spikes are from the fixedupdate function specifically. Is this enough information or should I check something else?

Comment: You'll need to share some of your physics code. It looks like you have some very inefficient memory allocation going on here. Otherwise, you can increase the physics timestep to reduce the number of fixedupdate calls per second.

Comment: @ErikOverflow I just shared my physics code. I am drawing trajectories of a predicted throw then I'm trying to find the 'optimal trajectory'

Comment: You are creating a lot of objects in each fixed update, I would start there.  Do those objects live forever, or do they get destroyed elsewhere?  Also, I doubt you need to find this lit shader n time per fixed update, once inside start will suffice.  Are you sure you want to create n materials each fixed update too?

Comment: @hijinxbassist Hi, I unload the scenes in an awake function that's called everytime a new object with this script attached is instantiated. Basically, once the last object hits the target, all items in this local physics scene get unloaded and a new physics scene is generated. Does unload scene not completely destroy all objects that are in the local physics scene?

Comment: Perhaps that is when you are seeing the GC spikes, during/after unloading the simulation scene objects?  I have not worked with scenes in this way, so I can only offer some basic optimization tips.  Start by removing the the `Shader.Find` and `new Material` code that is repeated in loops.  Find the shader once, and create the 2 materials you need once, no need to create additional objects that need to be released from memory.  Store them in a class variable for easy assignment in the next run (this also reduces the objects that get released by GC).